# how to create custom array using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

please advice me how to make an array like that using following 3 queries.

```
 $shiftsids = Shifts::select('id','shift_no', 'bus_no', 'shift_start_time', 'shift_end_time', 'run_type')
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                    ->where('week_id', '=', $week_id->id)
                    ->where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
                    ->get();


                $preCheck = DB::table('driver_pre_departure_items')
                    ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id')
                    ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                    ->where('driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                    ->get();

                $postCheck = DB::table('driver_shift_end_items')
                        ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_shift_end_items.shift_id')
                        ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                        ->where('driver_shift_end_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                        ->get();
```

this is how i want to out out the results.
i want to display preCheck and postCheck for each shift_id like below.
how can i proceed this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "shift_no": 1,
      "bus_no": "",
      "shift_start_time": "08:00:00",
      "shift_end_time": "10:00:00",
      "run_type": "S",
      "driver_pre_departure_items": [
        {
          "pre_departure_type": 1,
          "item_name": "Check all running lights & indicators",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "pre_departure_type": 2,
          "item_name": "Look for tyres that are flat or partly flat- check wheel nuts",
          "value": 0
        }
      ],
      "driver_shift_end_items": [
        {
          "shift_end_type": 1,
          "item_name": "Record any problems in defect book",
          "value": 0
        },
        {
          "shift_end_type": 2,
          "item_name": "Tell management or mechanic if there are any problems that require attention",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
```

UPDATED

```
                $array = array();

                $shiftsids = Shifts::select('id','shift_no', 'bus_no', 'shift_start_time', 'shift_end_time', 'run_type')
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                    ->where('week_id', '=', $week_id->id)
                    ->where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
                    ->get();

                foreach ($shiftsids as $shiftsid)
                {
                    $array[]['shift_no'] = $shiftsid->shift_no;
                    $array[]['shift_start_time'] = $shiftsid->shift_start_time;
                    $array[]['shift_end_time'] = $shiftsid->shift_end_time;


                    $preCheck = DB::table('driver_pre_departure_items')
                        ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id')
                        ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                        ->where('driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                        ->get();

                    foreach ($preCheck as $pch)
                    {
                        $array[]['driver_pre_departure_items'] = array('item' => $pch->item,'value' => $pch->value);
}
                    $postCheck = DB::table('driver_shift_end_items')
                        ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_shift_end_items.shift_id')
                        ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                        ->where('driver_shift_end_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                        ->get();
                    foreach ($postCheck as $pch)
                    {
                        $array[]['driver_shift_end_items'] = array('item' => $pch->item,'value' => $pch->value);
    }

                }
                return ['data' => $array];
```

New Output

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "shift_no": 1
    },
    {
      "shift_start_time": "08:00:00"
    },
    {
      "shift_end_time": "13:00:00"
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Check all running lights & indicators",
        "value": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Look for tyres that are flat or partly flat- check wheel nuts",
        "value": 0
      }
    },

    {
      "shift_no": 2
    },
    {
      "shift_start_time": "13:00:00"
    },
    {
      "shift_end_time": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Check all running lights & indicators",
        "value": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Look for tyres that are flat or partly flat- check wheel nuts",
        "value": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Check that tyres on dual wheels are not touching one another ",
        "value": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "driver_pre_departure_items": {
        "item": "Make sure that no liquids are leaking onto the road, or into the engine compartment",
        "value": 0
      }
    }

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();

$shiftsids = Shifts::select('id','shift_no', 'bus_no', 'shift_start_time', 'shift_end_time', 'run_type')
                    ->where('user_id', '=', $driver_id->id)
                    ->where('week_id', '=', $week_id->id)
                    ->where('time_sheet_id', '=', $timesheet_id->id)
                    ->get();

foreach ($shiftsids as $shiftsid) 
{


$zarray = array(
    ['shift_no'] => $shiftsid->id,
    // ...
    // ...
    // other parameters
);


$preCheck = DB::table('driver_pre_departure_items')
                ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id')
                ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                ->where('driver_pre_departure_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                ->get();
foreach ($preCheck as $pch) 
{
    $zarray['driver_pre_departure_items'][] = array('
        'pre_departure_type' => $pch->pre_departure_type;
    ')
}
$postCheck = DB::table('driver_shift_end_items')
                        ->join('shifts', 'shifts.id', '=', 'driver_shift_end_items.shift_id')
                        ->select('shift_id','item','value')
                        ->where('driver_shift_end_items.shift_id', '=', $shiftsid->id)
                        ->get();
foreach ($postCheck as $pch) 
    {
        $zarray['driver_pre_departure_items'][] = array('
            'pre_departure_type' => $pch->pre_departure_type;
        ')
    }

$array[] = $zarray;
}
```

Comment: I tried ur code, please check the UPDATED section on my question which i re-write ur code the way how i put. bit it didnt give the correct structre of array . please check and advice

Comment: can you dump the output ?

Comment: still driver_pre_departure_items and driver_shit_end_items comes seperatly